# Bad practice in a single page app to GET from one request and PUT to another and create sub models off a main model?

Tags: rest, backbone.js, models, single-page-application

The backend developer has designed the RESTful API in such a way that when going into a section of the site I call one large request for all the data in all the sub sections.  These sub sections data can be modified and saved.  If that happens I would need to create a new model based on the model from the large request, populate it, and save it to a different service (PUT).  This service can only PUT and not GET. I would probably create this model as soon as the user navigated to this section, and display the view based on this new model.  Now if i navigated to another sub section, that large request model would be out of date and I'd have to fetch it from the backend again instead of making a smaller request for that section.

I propose to him to just create separate services for each sub section that i can easily fetch and save to (I'm using Backbone).  Otherwise I'm creating sub models off a main model and they are dependent on each other and I'd have to write the code to wire them together instead of leveraging the power of the built in methods on the model like save, sync, fetch.

Does this not also create an issue in creating modular components if models are depending on other models?

Has anyone seen it done this way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation. Our API was designed under the philosophy that a single request should give everything needed to render a page. So there's one major API endpoint that returns a main data type, and all nested objects are returned in a partial state. So if I'm requesting "employees", the API won't give a "department id" it will return a partial department object like:

```
department: { "id": "1", "name": "Department A }
```

There are great benefits to this approach! Making multiple requests is expensive, and you don't want dozens of API hits for every page load. The problem you'll find is that Backbone was designed for one to one mappings between models and API endpoints. They don't give you anything like a Data Access Layer, if they did both our problems may be solved.

My team generally would make "department" an attribute for the Employee model. This has a big problem. The way that Backbone Models register changedAttributes doesn't play nice with complex objects in attributes, which complicates forms based on data structured this way. It's somewhat frowned upon by Backbone developers too. The general consensus is to store complex objects in a property of the Model class, rather than an attribute.

In any event your parse and toJSON methods will get a lot more complicated than what you'll typically find in examples.

Comment: Do you know if there are any frameworks that accommodate this situation better?

Comment: @neptunian I've been searching, but most MVP frameworks seem to be fighting over better ways to implement two way data binding. DAOs and Data Access Layers don't merit much attention, and most just wave them away. I still think Backbone can be made to work to account for this, but you'll have to deviate from their norms.

Comment: if you find one though, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use BreezeJS, which is built only for data rich application. Check out this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/730450/Creating-Single-Page-Application-using-Hot-Towel-T